# How to change draw order of MFC graph elements

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to modify the look of the graph displayed to have a white background with black axes.
However, simply modifying the RGB values of

```
  m_OScopeCtrl.SetBackgroundColor(RGB(0, 64, 0)) ;
  m_OScopeCtrl.SetGridColor(RGB(192, 255, 192)) ;
  m_OScopeCtrl.SetPlotColor(RGB(255, 255, 255)) ;
```

in “TestOScopeDlg.cpp” doesn’t seem to do the trick, the entire graph just turns white and the plots disappear (presumably being hidden by the white background).

Link to source code on codeproject.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/241/Oscilloscope-StripChart-Control

How can I make the graph appear with a white background and black axes?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Changing SRCPAINT to SRCAND works.

It seems SRCPAINT works when trying to overlay a **light** color on top of a **dark** color and SRCAND works when trying to overlay a **dark** color on top of a **light** color.